# Evaluating rate of change in repeated measure on an outcome

Tags: mixed-model, survival, repeated-measures

Here is a brief description of my problem set up. Retrospective observational cohort of people seen in the ED with pneumonia. Index day or start time is day disease diagnosed. Independent variable is a severity score on CXR (which can be taken multiple times at irregular intervals). Outcome variables are ICU admission and inpatient mortality. One example question of interest would be whether a high rate of change in your CXR severity score between the first (defined as CXR taken near index start) and second CXR can discriminate between people who will need ICU level care in the next 2-3 days.

Potential approaches? repeated measures ANOVA, mixed effect logistic regression, or cox regression with mixed effects (coxme package in R)? I'm very new to mixed effect modeling though and have a few questions:

- Any help or resources on better understanding how the output of these methods can be interpreted in plain English?
- I'm intrigued by the coxme approach, but am confused how you would deal with immortality bias when evaluating the change in a repeated measure of an independent variable (i.e. you have to live long enough to reach the second measure)
- Am I overthinking this? A simpler method (for me) would be to use multivariate logistic regression with binary outcome (ICU admission or death within a specified time frame) and include "first xray severity score" and "change in severity score on next xray" as separate variables. Have a feeling there are several limitations to this method though.

Any advice on which method and where to focus my energy to learn more is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a response variable you measure repeatedly over time for each patient in your study, which type of model you use will depend on factors such as the nature of that variable (e.g., continuous, count, binary, ordinal, nominal, time to event), the nature of your research question(s), the study design, the data, your statistical expertise and the level of statistical sophistication of your intended audience.

In general, a linear mixed effects model would be preferable to a repeated measures ANOVA for a continuous outcome variable (e.g., blood pressure), as it provides more flexibility.

Regardless of the nature of the response variable, mixed effects models which track patients repeatedly over time allow you to consider a minimum of two data hierarchy levels: patients (highest level) and occasions when response variable was measured (lowest level).  The occasions are considered to be nested within patients. With these two hierarchies, you have to realize that some predictors are measured at the lowest level (e.g., cholesterol level, measured at each occasion where the response variable was also measured), at the highest level (e.g., gender, recorded just once at the beginning of the study) or at both levels.

The predictors measured at the lowest level of the data hierarchy evolve through time so you need to be careful how you conceptualize them in your model. Are you going to include, for each occasion: their current value? their previous value? some aggregate value which considers all the predictor values up until that occasion? etc. The answer will depend on your research question(s).

Also important to consider is how you express time. Is time going to be treated as a discrete variable? continuous variable?

All mixed effects models have a so-called subject-specifc interpretation: they tell you what the effects of the predictor variables are on the (appropriate transformation of) expected value of the response variable for a *typical* subject.  Additionally, they also tell you how the other subjects differ from the *typical* subject with respect to the various effects included in the model.

One thing that you need to consider in mixed models with a two-level hierarchy is whether the predictors at the lowest level of your hierarchy have the same effects across all subjects represented by the ones included in your study (i.e., non-varying effects across subjects) or different effects (i.e., varying effects across subjects). The latter effects are called random effects.  The variation of these latter effects is assessed with respect to the effect corresponding to the *typical* subject.

There is plenty of literature on mixed effects models so you can just start reading a book - say, https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Applied+Mixed+Models+in+Medicine%2C+3rd+Edition-p-9781118778258.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful explanation! I've been reading around on some free resources, but it didn't quite click until I read through your explanation of the hierarchy in this context